# Plotting topic prevelance for each group [Structural Topic Modeling R]

Tags: r, time-series, topic-modeling, topicmodels

Community,

I have a question regarding the STM package for R and hope that you can help me find an answer.

In [figure 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtJP5.png) of the vignette the authors present a graph, where the topic prevalence (for topic 7) over time can be seen. Is it possible to plot the same graph by adding two further lines: one for liberal and one for conservative?

Liberal and conservative are attributes of the variable "rating"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot in figure 7 shows you the topic proportion of one topic (in this case topic 7) over a time span of January 2008 to December 2008. Basically, this graph shows you how your topic is distributed over a specific time frame. You can plot other topics in this graph, so yes, you can add more lines, but you cannot add a variable, like liberal/conservative, to plot in this graph.

Also, you might want to have a look at this -- it would be useful to add a reproducible example for clarity

[How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)